# Visual Studio Code not opening with 'code' command

Tags: bash, command-line, visual-studio-code

When I try to open VSCode from the command line with `code .`, I get the error `./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file located at `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code` and change `python` to `/usr/bin/python`.

Credit to [joaomoreno](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3941#issuecomment-194748532) for the solution.

Answer (score 29):

If you're getting following Error:

`/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory` 

`/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory`

Update `python` to `python3` in following File:

`/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`

Comment: This helped me! I went to /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin and opened the file with "nano code". In the sixth line I changed python to python3. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid changing VS Code files, you can add file named `python` to your path that just execs python3. For example, create a new file named `/usr/local/bin/python`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# work around missing `python` executable by calling `python3` 
exec python3 "$@"
```

Then `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/python`

After quitting and relaunching your shell to ensure paths are re-hashed, everything should work again.

Answer (score 2):

For people who face the issue of `-bash: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/: is a directory` despite following the solution by joaomoreno https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3941, please add `code` at the end of the file path: `alias code="/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code"`

Answer (score 0):

do you get this pop up when you try to install?

> EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/code'

If so, what worked for me was uninstalling via the `shift, cmd, P`, dropdown in vscode and re-installing. hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Probably (as I did) you changed something in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` etc.
just let vscode reinstall the command from the command palette, like this:

[image: activate 'code'command installation from vscode command palette]