# Problem running Visual Studio Code from Terminal on MacOS Catalina 10.15.5

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, macos-catalina

I have a problem getting Visual Studio Code to run from the command line. I have followed all available instructions and restarted my computer numerous times and although it is visibly there, it is still not possible. I have also added it within VSC with "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH".

Below the code from terminal:

```
J ~ % cat << EOF >> ~/.zshrc 
# Add Visual Studio Code (code) 
export PATH="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH" 
EOF

J ~ % cat .bash_profile

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7

# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"

J ~ % source .bash_profile

J ~ % code .
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code: line 6: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python: Bad CPU type in executable
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

All suggestions appreciated.
Many thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution:

Open the file located at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code and change python to /usr/bin/python.

I found the solution here:
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330359/visual-studio-code-not-opening-with-code-command)